# Search should allow single character queries for certain language sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

It appears that searches with single character queries are redirected to the site's search [help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search). For example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=e

This is acceptable, because with the English language there are few valid search terms that are only one characters long. However, for newer sites such as [Chinese Language and Usage](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/), a single Unicode character can be equivalent to one or more English *words*. I believe therefore that the restriction should be relaxed for these sites. For instance, a search like this:

> https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%8E%BA

is valid, and should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been enabled for chinese.SE and japanese.SE. Your [search link](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%8E%BA) now works, [as does this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E8%83%A1).

Comment: So where's korean.SE?

Comment: @TheGhost here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31223/korean-language-usage feel free to follow/support it