# One-character search terms should not always be stop words

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, symbols

I tried [searching for "ɣ" on Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%C9%A3).

Rather than performing the search, it displays the blank Search page. (With the previous search, it had displayed a search help page.)

Presumably, it assumes a 1-character query was typed accidentally. However, in this case, the 1-character query is an IPA symbol (voiced velar fricative) that produces relevant search results.

As a workaround, if you [search for "ɣ ɣ ɣ ɣ"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%C9%A3+%C9%A3+%C9%A3+%C9%A3), it *does* do the search. This proves that the necessary search functionality exists for 1-character search terms.

A similar feature [is enabled on Japanese Language and Usage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116444/search-should-allow-single-character-queries-for-certain-language-sites?rq=1): [searching for single Chinese characters](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E7%88%B6) works there, but [not on Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E7%88%B6).

The front-end should be changed to allow such searches.

Comment: It looks like another workaround is to add + to the character to make the character required (e.g. "+ɣ" will give the correct search).

Comment: Hang tight, we're replacing the search engine.

Comment: @Nick not completely sure whether that was sarcastic or not :)

Comment: @Pekka [it wasn't](http://imgur.com/3re0Z)

Comment: @NickCraver wow you only gave yourself 33K rep on your test machine? :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - just an old copy of meta that test is running on

Comment: @NickCraver Are you guys getting rid of Lucene?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - Lucene.net yes, elastic search is what we're migrating to, as a service model.

Comment: @NickCraver: The issue still exists with the new search.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed now, both on Linguistics and other sites I've checked.

Your search, for example, returns 36 results:

> [image]